# php regex find text within parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, powershell

Using PHP or Powershell I need help in finding a text in a text file.txt, within parenthesis then output the value.

Example:

`file.txt` looks like this:

```
This is a test I (MyTest: Test) in a parenthesis
    Another Testing (MyTest: JohnSmith) again. Not another testing testing (MyTest: 123)
```

My code:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.txt'); 
   $needle="MyTest"
preg_match('~^(.*'.$needle.'.*)$~', $content, $line);
```

Output to a new text file will be:

```
123Test, JohnSmith,123,
```

Comment: What does `$needle` contain?

Comment: my needle is "MyTest" however,i couldn't get the values following it.

Comment: You should use `preg_quote($needle)` to ensure any text your injecting into the regex gets escaped properly.

Comment: Don't forget to put a semi-colon at the end of `$needle="MyTest"` @Menew

Comment: where does the 123Test come from in the example output?

Answer (score 7):

Use this pattern:

```
~\(%s:\s*(.*?)\)~s
```

Note that `%s` here is not a part of the actual pattern. It's used by [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) to substitute the values that are passed as arguments. `%s` stands for string, `%d` for signed integer etc.

**Explanation:**

- `~` - starting delimiter
- `\(` - match a literal `(`
- `%s` - a placeholder for the `$needle` value
- `:` - match a literal `:`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace characters
- `(.*?)` - match (and capture) anything inside the parentheses
- `\)` - match a literal `)`
- `~` - ending delimiter
- `s` - a [pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) that makes `.` match newlines as well

**Code:**

```
$needle  =  'MyTest';
$pattern = sprintf('~\(%s:\s*(.*?)\)~s', preg_quote($needle, '~'));
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Test"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "JohnSmith"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/136340)

Comment: it gave me empty array:$needle  =  'MyTest:';
$content = file_get_contents('file.txt'); 
$pattern = sprintf('~\(%s:(.*?)\)~s', preg_quote($needle, '~'));
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);

Comment: @Menew: Your needle contains the semicolon. That's not needed as I've added that inside the pattern. Make it `$needle = 'MyTest';` (note the **absence of semicolon**).

Comment: @Menew: I've updated the answer to the matches doesn't include any whitespace in the beginning. Glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Powershell solution:

```
@'
This is a test I (MyTest: Test) in a parenthesis
    Another Testing (MyTest: JohnSmith) again. Not another testing testing (MyTest: 123) 
'@ | set-content test.txt


([regex]::Matches((get-content test.txt),'\([^:]+:\s*([^)]+)')|
 foreach {$_.groups[1].value}) -join ','

Test,JohnSmith,123
```

You can add that trailing comma after it's done if you really did want that there....